# Exporting ARIMA forecasting result into excel file

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, export, xlsx

I need to store arima forecast result into Excel file, file should contain first column as account which is coming from different variable and forecasted dataframe for that perticular account no.
Following is my code:

```
df <- read.csv("dataset.csv")
library (tseries)
library (forecast)
loopvec <- c(unique(df$account_number))
for (loopitem in loopvec){
    df2 <- subset(df, account_number==loopitem) 
    x = ts(df2$amount, start = c(2015,1), end = c(2020,12), frequency = 
    12)
    arima1 = auto.arima(x)
    forecast1 = forecast(arima1,h = 1)
    write.table(forecast1, file = "Forecast_Results.csv", col.names=NA, 
    append = T)
    write.table(loopitem, file = "accountnumbers.csv", col.names=NA, append = 
    T)
}
```

I want to write these results in one excel file, which look like this:

```
`Account#    Month      Point Forecast   Lo.80 Hi.80 Lo.95 Hi.95
A            July 2019  100              80    83    102   114
A            201902     120              95    102   127   138
A            201903     135              110   117   142   158
B            201901     0                0     0     1     4.23
B            201902     0                0     0     1     3.75
B            201903     20               17    18    22    25
C            201901     0                0     0     0.06  2
C            201902     1700             1515  1585  1787  1920
C            201903 1400
```

Currently the csv results are:

Result.csv:

```
 "Point.Forecast" "Lo.80" "Hi.80" "Lo.95" "Hi.95"
Jul 2019 -7019257.05555555 -21898155.8001267 7859641.6890156 
-29774569.0172597 15736054.9061486
"Point.Forecast" "Lo.80" "Hi.80" "Lo.95" "Hi.95"
Jul 2019 -188594598.720274 -291947989.598493 -85241207.8420547 
-346659969.827926 -30529227.6126215
```

accountnumbers.csv

```
 "x"
 1 A
 "x"
 1 B
 "x"
 1 C
```

Comment: Looks like you changed model from Prophet to ARIMA, lets solve this problem also.

Comment: i am not supposed to do anything outside code so pasting in excel is not an option

Comment: and can you please suggest a code for writing code results data frame

Answer (score 0):

Here you are storing each forecasted point every time in csv file when you loop acc no.
It will take lot of time if you have lot of data. Instead of that take one temp data frame
and store acc no forecasted dataframe there, and when your loop complete store that data frame into csv file.

After doing above change use "clip board" function with the help of that you can directly copy your R data frame and paste into Excel.

```
 write.table(RDATAFRAME, "clipboard", sep="\t", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

After executing above code, go to excel file and press Ctrl + V (paste) it.